# How to get a definite type when accessing an object?

Tags: typescript

```js
interface MyProps {
  x: number;
  y: string;
}

const myVar: MyProps = {
  x: 1,
  y: '2',
};

function getMyValue(prop?: keyof MyProps) {
  if (prop) {
    return myVar[prop];
  }
  return myVar;
}

const x = getMyValue('x');
const y = getMyValue('y');
const val = getMyValue();
```

Now I get the type of `x` is `string | number | MyProps`, but what I expect `x` is `number`, `y` is `string`, and `val` is `MyProps`. So, how to do that?

Comment: In general, when you want a more specific return type from a function based on arguments, you want [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads): https://tsplay.dev/WoJQam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

```
interface MyProps {
  x: number;
  y: string;
}

const myVar: MyProps = {
  x: 1,
  y: '2',
};

function getMyValue<Prop extends keyof MyProps = keyof MyProps>(prop: Prop): MyProps[Prop]

function getMyValue(): MyProps

function getMyValue<Prop extends keyof MyProps = keyof MyProps>(prop?: Prop): MyProps[Prop] | MyProps {
  if (prop) {
    return myVar[prop];
  }
  return myVar;
}
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8AKUD2AHAZ2QG8AoZZADwC5kQBXAWwCNoBuc5dWgsKUAOYcAvqVIIcIXskboAanCi0M2fEQC8JTjWQBGADSduyAOQAmE4eEdSMeiARhgk5AIhgMCgDb0IAHlU8ZAhKSBAAEyIAawh0HBg0LFxCZE0YuISVZIIAPgAKPGTaQIBKZSS1AG1AgF1be0dnEFd3TzgfCDyyxMCCMTsHJxc3D3l23wDk4NCICOjY%20J7s1OR0xay1fML8AH5i5O6NwmrkmuQAHyW1LQpgBIKDm4pkKHd6KGbZBShK7bwajgUUQUV5gd6fMZQERiCRSMBUFYjNodPImSgmEocWHSdCI1pjFEmdAYrGSaQAN3aeNG3l8XTYQA)